# Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx - always only shows the welcome page

Tags: nginx

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 default `nginx` configuration, with some minor changes. But I always sees the nginx's default welcome message. All config files follows:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

This file is empty. And this directory only contains one file.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
upstream backend {

         server 127.0.0.1:8068;

}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

#       server_name _;

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
       }

}
```

On the server, the http server runs correctly:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8068
some contents...
```

In another computer, only the welcome message shows:

```
$ curl http://the-server-ip-address
the default welcome to nginx message follows...
```

I've also tried to access the ip address in my Chrome and disabled caches, but the same welcome page always shows.

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows no access logs and no errors.

Does my nginx config files have a problem? Thanks!

(I just tried the same config files on a 16.04 ubuntu server and it works correctly.)

I've run the follow commands to test and reload the configs:

```
$ nginx -t
$ nginx -s reload
```

### updated

Sorry, I just tried some other operation:

I run the following command on this server:

```
$ ifconfig
```

and get the ip address is `192.***` rather than the ip address I used to access(ssh to) this server.

I run

```
$ curl 192.***:80
```

and the server responds correctly.

But why the ip address I used to `ssh` to the server always shows the welcome page?

```
$ curl the-server-ip-address-for-ssh:80
still the welcome page...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you reload or restart `nginx`?

Comment: I've tried that.